# Two dice probability problem

Tags: probability

I have two dice. One is completely ordinary, the other has a $\frac23$ chance to roll a $6$. I roll one dice, and its a $6$. What are the chances that it was the ordinary one?

How am I suppose to solve this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you heard of Bayes' rule ?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the ordinary dice "Dice A" and the biased dice "Dice B".

The probability of rolling a 6 with Dice A is $\frac{1}{6}$, and the probability of rolling a 6 with Dice B is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Let's denote the event of rolling a 6 with Dice A as "A" and the event of rolling a 6 with Dice B as "B".

We want to find the probability that we rolled Dice A given that we rolled a 6, i.e. we want to find $P(A|6)$.

Using Bayes' Theorem, we have:

$P(A|6) = P(6|A) * P(A) / P(6)$

where P(6) is the probability of rolling a 6 with either dice, which can be calculated as:

$P(6) = P(6|A) * P(A) + P(6|B) * P(B)$

Substituting the probabilities, we have:

$P(6) = (1/6) * (1/2) + (2/3) * (1/2) = 5/12$

$P(A|6) = P(6|A) * P(A) / P(6) = (1/6) * (1/2) / (5/12) = 1/5$

Therefore, the probability that the dice that was rolled was Dice A given that we rolled a 6 is $1/5$ or 20%. Thank you for bringing this to my attention, and I apologize for any confusion my previous response may have caused.

Comment: You aren't supposed to directly answer a question where the asker hasshown no effort whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. I hope this answer should be a hint.

Comment: Thanks, for answering it. But using Bayes shouldnt be the final answer 1/5?

Comment: Thanks my mistake and revised.